# BAPI_PO_CREATE1 Account 475000 requires an assignment to a CO object

Tags: abap, bapi, sap-erp

I've found two functions, `BAPI_PO_CREATE` and `BAPI_PO_CREATE1`. Since the `CREATE1` has a more recent modification date, I assumed this would be the best one to use. As an example, I'm creating a rather simple purchase without a material.

```
call function 'BAPI_PO_CREATE1'
  exporting
    poheader   = po_header
    poheaderx  = po_header_x
    testrun    = abap_false
  tables
    return     = returning
    poitem     = po_items
    poitemx    = po_items_x
    poaccount  = po_accounts
    poaccountx = po_accounts_x
    poschedule = po_schedule
    poschedulex = po_schedule_x.
```

As such, I'm using a G/L Account and WBS element as the cost object:

```
append initial line to po_accounts assigning field-symbol(<po_account>).
<po_account>-po_item = current_position.
" Classes that call CONVERSION_EXIT
<po_account>-gl_account = /dim/cl_bonadm_exit=>int_saknr( <item>-gl_account ).
<po_account>-wbs_element = /dim/cl_bonadm_exit=>int_posnr( <item>-wbs_id ).

append initial line to po_accounts_x assigning field-symbol(<po_account_x>).
<po_account_x>-po_item = current_position.
<po_account_x>-po_itemx = abap_true.
<po_account_x>-gl_account = abap_true.
<po_account_x>-wbs_element = abap_true.
```

However, the I continue to get the error message:

```
No instance of object type PurchaseOrder has been created. External reference:
Purchase order item 00010 still contains faulty account assignments
Can delivery date be met?
Account 475000 requires an assignment to a CO object
```

Which shouldn't be the case, when I fill in the same exact data in ME21n I still get the delivery date warning but not the error on purchase order item. I have come across two different SAP notes but neither of them can be implemented. As well, even when I remove the WBS element from the account I still get the error message.

I've also tried filling in the WBS element in the CO-object field of the BAPI structure, but that did nothing. I can trace the point in the BAPI where it throws this error message but I can't find out why it's happening.

Entire method: http://hastebin.com/ufarisozav.xml

Answer (score 0):

You will need to fill the table `poaccountx` as well (as shown in the documentation of the function module), otherwise the system might ignore some or all of the data inserted into the `poaccount` table.

Comment: I've filled this in as well, I just didn't include the code snippet, added to post

Comment: That is why a *complete* sample is so important. Did you also fill `SERIAL_NO` and forgot to paste that?

Comment: nope, let me throw something in it and see. Edit: nothing changed, I've included a snippet of the entire method.

Comment: You need to provide the `SERIAL_NO` in both `poaccount` and `poaccountx`.

Comment: I've filled in those fields, it makes no difference. There is also something I find quite weird. When I don't provide a GL account or I use a different account, the table I sent to the BAPI has a different GL account filled in (e.g. I put 800 and I see that it turns into 475000 and reports that)

Comment: As it says, the account is a cost element and therefore needs a CO object. It is message KI 235. Search SAP notes for it. You will find plenty of SAP notes for it. If WBS-Element is non statistical it should work. Maybe try just for testing purposes a cost center.

Refer also to SAP note 2217322.

Comment: Check also account assignment category in line item and read documentation of BAPI. It is well documented.